# Why is it showing makefile not found?

Tags: visual-studio-code, makefile, gdb, mingw

The code is not compiling on VSCode. I am using the MingW compiler for C++ and it's showing this:

[image]

Earlier, the terminal that I was using was powershell integrated into VSCode, which showed [this](https://github.com/PowerShell/vscode-powershell/issues/1536) error , but now the above is happening when I am using Git Bash terminal.

I have tried searching on internet but couldn't find anything helpful. What should I do from here?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Where is it saying `makefile not found`?

Comment: @ssbssa see the error in the bottom left of the screen

Comment: The error is that the `.exe` file is not in executable format, so it looks like it got built (compile+link) wrong.